# Algebra problem (deriving a variable in a formula)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I derive the $m$ in the formula:
$$I=\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{mn} -1$$

all the values of the variables in the formula except $m$ is given and the question is find $m$.
I just don't know how to derive the formula using the knowledge of Algebra I have.

Comment: In order to solve equations like these, you need the [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Also, numerical methods. Could you clarify what you can use (Newton method ?) ?

Comment: @DavidH. Are you sure you could ? Just curious. Cheers :) OK, I checked but this leads to amonster, isn't ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: In fact you can not.

Comment: Do you have specific values?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal. In fact you can if you write $$(I+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^m$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The expression I found was a ghastly creature indeed. Not something I'd expect from an algebra-precalc student.

Comment: @DavidH. Me neither ! Once I asked if there is a limit to teachers imagination.

Comment: $m$ is probably an integer. Try all values from $1$. If you find two values that bracket $I$ without reaching it, you can refine $m$ by dichotomic search. (There are more efficient methods but let's keep it simple for now.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer by David, we set $t=\dfrac rm$, and

$$\sqrt[nr]{1+I}=(1+t)^{1/t}=s,$$
or
$$1+t=s^t=e^{t\ln(s)}.$$

Then
$$(1+t)s=e^{(1+t)\ln(s)},$$
$$-(1+t)\ln(s)\,e^{-(1+t)\ln(s)}=-\frac{\ln(s)}s,$$
and 
$$-(1+t)\ln(s)=W(-\frac{\ln(s)}s).$$
Hence,
$$m=\frac r{-\dfrac{W(-\frac{\ln(s)}s)}{\ln(s)}-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a compound interest question, so we see that the somewhat esoteric Lambert-W function may soon be part of the technical toolbox of chartered accountants! in order to gain a clearer idea of what is happening, using only elementary algebra, OP may find it useful to make an initial substitution, say $ x = \frac{m}{r} $, so that the equation becomes:
$$
I=(1+x^{-1})^{nrx} -1
$$
or
$$
\sqrt[nr]{1+I} = (1+x^{-1})^x
$$
where the LHS is a constant  computable from the problem data